# post json string from javascript to ajax at javascript prototype

Tags: php, javascript, json, prototype

I have got an issue with passing a json object to ajax at prototype.
here is the situation:
PHP:

```
<?php
    $a = array(k1=>v1, k2=>v2);
    $a = json_encode($a);
?>//JS 
<script>
    var a_js = <?= $a ?>
</script>
<?
    echo '<input type:"button" onclick='save(a_js) value='save js''>';
?>
```

JS

```
function save(a_json) {
    AJAX_ACTIONS_URL = 'ajax_action.php';
    params = {
        act: 'save_filters_status',
        a_json: a_json
    };
    new Ajax.Request(AJAX_ACTIONS_URL, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: params,
        onSuccess: function (transport) {
            alert(transport.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Ajax_actions.php

```
if(var_post('act')=='save_filters_status') {
    $x = explode(',',var_post('a_js'));
    print_r($x);
}
```

Now, I don't see any post for `a_js` at fire fox, there is no response from the ajax, and I am a bit lost, thanks for your help..
Notice I work at JavaScript prototype frame work..

Comment: '<input type:"button" onclick="save(a_js)" value="save js">'

Comment: hey i think my problem was that i havent use JSON.stringify at the js parts  after get the var from the php.. so this is still an object. because this the output default between php ->js.. thanks for your help. sorry for posting syntax errors..

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo`'d button has some faulty quote nesting:

```
 echo '<input type:"button" onclick='save(a_js) value='save js''>';
```

Should be:

```
 echo '<input type="button" onclick="save(a_js)" value="save js">';
```

Comment: I'd add that `type:"button"` isn't valid either.

Comment: @Ranty: Derp, how could I have missed that! Thanks!

Comment: i change it, but still he cant the json, when using alert at the js part i get (object object)

Comment: @AmirMaman: Apparently `transport.responseText` is a object, then. Can you `console.log()` it, to see it's actual contents?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
  $a=array(k1=>v1, k2=>v2)
  $a = json_encode($a)
  ?>//JS 
  <script>
    var a_js='<?=$a?>';
  </script>
  <?
  echo '<input type:"button" onclick='save(a_js) value='save js''>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i think my problem was that i havent use JSON.stringify at the js parts  after get the var from the php.. so this is still an object. because this the output default between php ->js.. thanks for your help. sorry for posting syntax errors..